# Can't run angular 2 project on Ubuntu

Tags: angular, ubuntu, npm

I am trying run angular 2 project on Ubuntu.

I have installed nodejs: `sudo apt-get install nodejs`

Installed angular: `sudo npm install -g @angular/cli`

and when I run my project via `sudo npm install` and `npm run start`

I get this returned:

```
$sudo npm install npm WARN angular-star-rating@4.0.0-beta.3 requires a

peer of css-star-rating@^1.2.4 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself. 
npm WARN angular2-jwt@0.2.3 requires a peer of @angular/core@^2.0.0||^4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself. 
npm WARN angular2-jwt@0.2.3 requires a peer of @angular/http@^2.0.0||^4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself. 
npm WARN ng2-custom-validation@1.2.4 requires a peer of @angular/core@>=2.0.0 <5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself. 
npm WARN ng2-custom-validation@1.2.4 requires a peer of @angular/forms@>=2.3.1 <5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

up to date in 11.88s


   ╭─────────────────────────────────────╮    
   │                                     │    
   │   Update available 5.6.0 → 6.2.0    │    
   │     Run npm i -g npm to update      │    
   │                                     │    
   ╰─────────────────────────────────────╯

$ npm run start

> ng-universal-demo@0.0.0 start /var/www/html/frontend
> ng serve

** NG Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **  
10% building modules 3/3 modules 0 activeKilled                                    
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE 
npm ERR! errno 137 
npm ERR! ng-universal-demo@0.0.0 start: `ng serve` 
npm ERR! Exit status 137 
npm ERR!  
npm ERR! Failed at the ng-universal-demo@0.0.0 start script. 
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Also it just hangs there on this:

```
10% building modules 3/3 modules 0 active
```

What am I doing wrong? I am running this on Google Cloud Platform Ubuntu VM with f1-micro (1 vCPU, 0.6 GB memory)

Please help!

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to deploy using the dev server - don't do that, just serve the built files.

Comment: I tried that, it just hangs on 10% building modules 3/3 modules 0 active

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Haven't fixed it yet but I have a feeling Linux is killing processes because you are running out of memory.

Comment: Correct, my issue was fixed with more memory